# Opposite of includes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, eager-loading

Assuming I have

```
#post.rb

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

default_scope includes(:user)
```

what do I do when I don't want to include the user when I fetch a post?

for instance, when I delete a post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the unscoped scope. Method reference: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Default/ClassMethods/unscoped

For example, when trying to delete the Post object :

```
def destroy
  @post = Post.unscoped.find(params[:id])
  # destroy code here
end
```

This will search in your database without any scope.